# Envoy,gRPC Issue Could not load server reflection. Details: 14 UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers

Tags: .net, docker, grpc, envoyproxy

I'm new to envoy. I'm trying to proxy 2 gRPC microservice request using envoy.
Service1 by accessing 8080 port and
Service2 in 8083 port and then When we try to connected through Envoy API gateway by using the Port 8084 it shows the following error

*Could not load server reflection. Details: 14 UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111*
Here is my envoy.yaml file

```
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9902             
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8084 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              codec_type: auto
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                  - name: local_service
                    domains: ["*"]
                    routes:
                      - match: { prefix: "/serv1" }
                        route:
                          cluster: service1
                          timeout: 60s
                          max_stream_duration:
                            grpc_timeout_header_max: 60s
                      - match: { prefix: "/serv2" }
                        route:
                          cluster: service2
                          timeout: 60s
                          max_stream_duration:
                            grpc_timeout_header_max: 60s       
                    cors:
                      allow_origin_string_match:
                        - prefix: "*"
                      allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                      allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                      max_age: "1728000"
                      expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
              http_filters:
                - name: envoy.grpc_json_transcoder
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: service1
      connect_timeout: 1.25s
      type: logical_dns
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      # http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: service1
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: 0.0.0.0
                    port_value: 8080
    - name: service2
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: static
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      # http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: service2
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: 0.0.0.0
                    port_value: 8083
```

- here is my docker-compose.yaml

version: "3.8"

services:
envoygateway:
build: ./Envoy
volumes:
- ./Envoy/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
ports:
- "8084:8084"
networks:
- grpc_network

service1:
build:
context: ./service1
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
networks:
  - grpc_network
```

service2:
build:
context: ./service2
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

```
ports:
  - "8083:8083"
networks:
  - grpc_network
```

networks:
grpc_network:
driver: bridge